# Django how to add value from model into another application's view?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-views

I have 2 applications in my "aplikacja" django project:

- articles
- qr

From articles model I would like to get a value "title" from the first article and then put it into qr.views (it prepares for me a pdf file)

Articles models:

```
from django.db import models

class Article(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
        content = models.TextField(verbose_name="Zawartosc")
        published = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Data Publikacji")
```

How to get a "title" value into qr views?
I suppose I need to import article from aplikacja.articles.models. But how to get exactly value in test_qr method?

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from django.http import HttpResponse
from reportlab.graphics.shapes import Drawing 
from reportlab.graphics.barcode.qr import QrCodeWidget 
from reportlab.graphics import renderPDF
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from aplikacja.articles.models import article


def test_qr(request):
    # Create the HttpResponse object with the appropriate PDF headers.
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.pdf"'

    a= map(lambda x: str(x), User.objects.values_list('id', flat=True).order_by('id'))

    p = canvas.Canvas(response)
    p.drawString(10, 800, a[1])

    qrw = QrCodeWidget(a[1]) 
    b = qrw.getBounds()

    w=b[2]-b[0] 
    h=b[3]-b[1] 

    d = Drawing(200,200,transform=[200./w,0,0,200./h,0,0]) 
    d.add(qrw)

    renderPDF.draw(d, p, 1, 1)

    p.showPage()
    p.save()
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the first article use the `first()` method:

```
article = article.objects.all().order_by('published').first()
title = article.title if article else None
```

BTW python lists are zero based so to get the first element of a list you should use `a[0]` instead of `a[1]`.  But anyway I suggest you to use the same `first()` method to get the `id` of the first user:

```
first_user_id = str(User.objects.values_list('id', flat=True) \
                                .order_by('id').first())
```